# JScrollpanel in Fancybox not working correctly

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jquery-jscrollpane

im using  fancybox from:

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

And the scroll pane is not working correctly and just wondered if im doing something wrong below with the code. its added the pane in but not the scrollbar its self so im asusming needs to fire after fancybox  but might be wrong with what i have done below

```
var scrollpane;    
$(document).ready(function() {      
    // start up the overlay
    $("a#addtatic-overlay").fancybox({
        helpers:  {
            overlay : {
                opacity: 0.35   
            }
        },
        'afterLoad' : (function(){
            //custom scroll bar
            scrollpane = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
        }),
        'afterClose' : (function(){
            scrollpane.destroy();
        })
    });

    // Slider
    $("#slidecontainer").muslider({
        "animationtype": "horizontal",
        "animationduration": 600,
        "height": 500,
        "width": 835
    });

    // Forms
    $("input, textarea, select").uniform();
});
```

Comment: Maybe change callback 'afterLoad' to 'beforeShow' (or 'afterShow')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is happening when you start fancybox? Is #slidecontainer showing up at all? If not maybe look here:

http://fancybox.net/howto

inline example:

```
<a id="inline" href="#data">This shows content of element who has id="data"</a>

<div style="display:none"><div id="data">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div></div>
```

Comment: if i take it out of the fancybox works fine and shows the scroller, when in the fancybox its adding in the jscrollpane html as expected apart from the actual scroller html it normal generates - i.e its missing the div jspVerticalBar and div jspTrack  its strange